# Is it "à" or "en" in relation to a job location?

Tags: traduction, indications-de-lieu

When referring to a job at Apple located in Cupertino. Do you write:

> Développeur chez Apple à Cupertino

or

> Développeur chez Apple en Cupertino

Answer (score 1):

The possible duplicate that @Toto mentioned in his comment contains exhaustive information regarding the subject of prepositions and the case of cities, countries and the like. In brief

> Développeur chez Apple à Cupertino

because Cupertino is a city. Furthermore

> Je vais à Paris, à Boston, à Brest, à Grenonble,...

For masculine countries that their first letter is a consonant or for countries in plural (le Portugal, le Danemark, les États-Unis), since à+le-->au and à+les-->aux we use

> au Portugal, au Danemark, aux États-Unis, etc.

For feminine countries and masculine one that start with a vowel we use en

> en France (f), en Iran (m), en Espagne (f),...

For feminine regions or masculines that start with a vowel we use also en

> en Normandie (f), en Provence (f), en Anjou (m)

For islands whose name contains article we use also en

> en Corse (la Corse), en Sicile (la Sicile)...

Comment: Note that the contraction à+le=au also applies if the place name has a "le" that is an integral part of the name. Ex: Le Havre => *je vais au Havre*.